# Is there a row limitation for Data>Remove Duplicates function in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a bizarre situation. I had made some research but i could not found the answer. As you see in the screenshot below, even there are highlighted duplicates, Data>Remove Duplicates function cannot specify multiple rows. After making some sorting, it becomes able to find and remove those duplicate values.

[image: List of duplicate values, visual]

Why is this happening? Also, if there is a way to extend its limitation, would you guys help me how to do it?

Regards,

I tried to remove duplicate values in a list, but it does not work properly. I want to make it work properly.

Comment: Try first using Text To Columns to somewhat sanitize the data before running Remove Duplicates

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however the data is already sanitized, It has been taken through an ERP system. Am i understanding incorrectly, what do you mean by sanitized? Thanks.

Comment: Ah well I notice that some of the values are stored as numbers and some are stored as text. Sometimes that can confuse `Remove Duplicates` and prevent it from recognizing two seemingly identical values as identical. That's why I suggested giving `Text to Columns` a shot. It might work it might not lol